# how should a file storage service has to be designed when the storage is on one server and the service is on another server?

Tags: wcf-data-services, cloud-storage

my company has bought huge storage for applications to store files. There may always be a chance that our company may choose a different storage provider in future. So, instead of directly accessing the storage by using its REST services I want to design a wrapper on top of it so that the underlying storage can be changed when required without too many changes.

The service (REST) I am going to create lives on a different server than the storage server. is this a better approach? because I see that when client uploads a file by consuming the service the file has to be first loaded on to my server and then it will be pushed to the storage server.

What should be the better way of architecting something like this? We prefer doing this in .NET but we can choose a different technology if that is a proper fit.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on what you're trying to optimize. Your approach optimizes development time for your client applications in the event that your backend storage API changes. If you anticipate that your backend storage API will change frequently then this is a valid optimization, and I would say that you're on the right track. I would use something like WCF (not necessarily WCF DataServices, which is more targeted toward structured data such as a database).

However, if you're Backend storage API will change infrequently, then it may not be worth the added overhead of an additional wrapper layer.

That would be the deciding question for me, how frequently do you anticipate changes to your backend storage API?

Comment: the one we are currently using was there for more than 2 years. Architects wants us to build a decoupled solution so that in future if backend changes there wont be much impact to clients consuming the service. If we build a service which is on a different server wont it have performance issues because the file has to move through multiple servers

Comment: assuming you run each server on different physical hardware then yes, you've just essentially doubled your network traffic. At the minimum I would consider co-locating the services on the same hardware.